# ModuleNotFoundError: Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-module

- I am calling a module inside `urbancloth` package from `home.py`
- This runs the  `__init__` file but doesn't run another module present in urbancloth.
- The directory structure is as follows -
  [image]
- The code in `home.py`:

```
from urbancloth import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug =True)
```

- The code in `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'b0fe7021532f0541f87226aafd71ec77'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from urbancloth import routes
```

and the error message is-
[image]

[I am following Sir CoreySchafers Flask tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44PvX0Yv368&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=5)

[Github for original code](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/05-Package-Structure)

Comment: Check typos:urabncloth -> urbancloth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will look at you error closely 
`from urabncloth import app`

Looking at your directory there is no `urabncloth` it is `urbancloth`. Just a typo.
 So in your `routes.py` change the package name.

*Hope this solves your problem!!!*